# read write split in aws aurora at application level

Tags: amazon-aurora

best approach for read write split in aws aurora and how we do that at application level

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are basically various approach for this.
Best of it is:
 1. You can use read and writer end points in your application to split read and write query.
 2. Or you can use proxy sql, it will does the same for you.